# Update existing nodes not created by Feeds module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-feeds

I'm looking for a way to update existing nodes that were not created by the Feeds module, that already works fine with a field dedicated to GUID element.

I decided to create a new record in the table feeds_node_item after creating a node(*hook_save, is_new*), with the GUID element.

The problem is that they do not know how to create the hash code.

How feeds import create de hash code?

Any solutions are welcome.
Many thanks

Comment: Have you looked a the code in the Feeds module to see how they build their hash?

Comment: Ok, I know, I found perhaps the function that I need `feeds_item_info_insert`